# Resteasy(client proxy framework) Response Close error if call readEntity on Response with 500 HTTP status

Tags: web-services, resteasy

Writing web service using Resteasy framework.

Need to send error message to the client with HTTP 500 Response if any exception thrown while processing on server.

I have void method in WebService interface as :

```
public interface WebLocationService {

@DELETE
@Path("/delete")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public void deleteLocation(LocationId locationId); { }
```

If this method throw any Exception then ExceptionMapper catches it and return response with 500 status and exception message as entity.

```
public class WebApplicationExceptionMapper implements                 
                                     ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException>{

@Override
public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException e) {
    return Response.serverError().entity(e.getMessage()).build();
} }
```

Using Resteasy client proxy framework.

For Response with 500 status, client proxy framework throw ServerErrorException and wrap response with it. Get response from the ServerErrorException. When i call readEntity or getEntity on response, it throws Response close error with IllegalStateException.

Debugged it and find out, based on web service interface method return type , proxy framework decides EntityExtractor.

**1)** For void return type, DefaultEntityExtractor$3 buffers the entity inputstream and then close the response.

**2)** For Response, Response.Status and ResponseObject, DefaultEntityExtractor$1,$2,$4 do not close the response.

**3)** For any other type, BodyEntityExtractor is entity extractor and do not close the response.